# How do I save/load value for custom input in 2sxc module?

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

How do I save/load value for custom input in 2sxc module? I need plain text input but I don't see how can I load/save value for it... Is it something that needs to be executed inside `init` function and do something with `this.connector.data`?

Comment: Can you flesh this out a little more? Are you creating your own custom input? Can you give an example of what you are trying to load/save? 2sxc has built in features for placeholders and default values, are either of those similar to what you are trying to do? Or are you trying to create your own Input in your Razor View? If yes, to that last Q, I recommend exploring the Mobius Forms (2sxc App), that has lots of great examples of various types of input fields.

Comment: I was trying to create simple text input just like 2sxc string default one, but add some custom validation there via js. But I didn't succeed in such a simple thing as save/load data. Also I stumbled upon an issue of making it look with same exact styling as default one. But `<input type="text" />` in the html just simply messed everything up. So a simple task turned into something very hard and complicated so far.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use the custom-field feature. See https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/custom-fields/index.html